# Can't receive phone call on my FreePbx extension

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I'm running out of hair to pull here. I have my freepbx installed and configured ok at the beginning. I was testing it with Google Voice account. I can call out and receive call. I'm sure I must did something when I was trying to configure a new DID from Voip.ms. Suddenly my sip phone can't dial out. Tried to call extension to extension and having the same problem also. Please help?

```
My Phone (Info Scrubbed): 2065551212  
Destination Dial: 2065551234
FreePbx 2.11.0.10
Asterisk 11
OS: Centos 6.4 64Bit
```

**Here is my outbound setting.**

```
Route Name: mygvoicegmail.com
dial patterns:
prepend + prefix | match pattern /callerid
empty + empty | 1NXXNXXXXXX /2065551212
1 + empty | NXXNXXXXXX /2065551212
Trunk Sequence:
GVM_2065551212
Optional Destination on Congestion: Normal Congestion
```

**Here is the log on what's happening when I tried to call out.**

```
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10674][C-00000006] netsock2.c: == Using SIP RTP CoS mark 5
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [12065551234@from-internal:1] Macro("SIP/8881-00000006", "user-callerid,LIMIT,") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:1] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "TOUCH_MONITOR=1379019883.6") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:2] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "AMPUSER=8881") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:3] GotoIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "0?report") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:4] ExecIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "1?Set(REALCALLERIDNUM=8881)") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:5] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "AMPUSER=8881") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:6] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "AMPUSERCIDNAME=MyHomeExt") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:7] GotoIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "0?report") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:8] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "AMPUSERCID=8881") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:9] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "__DIAL_OPTIONS=Ttr") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:10] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "CALLERID(all)="MyHomeExt" ") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:11] GotoIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "0?limit") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:12] ExecIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "1?Set(GROUP(concurrency_limit)=8881)") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:13] ExecIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "0?Set(CHANNEL(language)=)") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:14] GosubIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "7?sub-ccss,s,1(from-internal,12065551234)") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:1] ExecIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "0?Return()") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:2] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "CCSS_SETUP=TRUE") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@sub-ccss:3] GosubIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "0?monitor_config,1(from-internal,12065551234):monitor_default,1(from-internal,12065551234)") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [monitor_default@sub-ccss:1] GotoIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "0?is_exten") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [monitor_default@sub-ccss:2] StackPop("SIP/8881-00000006", "") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [monitor_default@sub-ccss:3] Return("SIP/8881-00000006", "FALSE") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:15] GotoIf("SIP/8881-00000006", "1?continue") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Goto (macro-user-callerid,s,28)
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:28] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "CALLERID(number)=8881") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:29] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "CALLERID(name)=MyHomeExt") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:30] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "CDR(cnum)=8881") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:31] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "CDR(cnam)=MyHomeExt") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [s@macro-user-callerid:32] Set("SIP/8881-00000006", "CHANNEL(language)=en") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [12065551234@from-internal:2] NoCDR("SIP/8881-00000006", "") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [12065551234@from-internal:3] Progress("SIP/8881-00000006", "") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:43] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [12065551234@from-internal:4] Wait("SIP/8881-00000006", "1") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:44] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [12065551234@from-internal:5] Progress("SIP/8881-00000006", "") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:44] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [12065551234@from-internal:6] Playback("SIP/8881-00000006", "silence/1&cannot-complete-as-dialed&check-number-dial-again,noanswer") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:44] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] file.c: -- <SIP/8881-00000006> Playing 'silence/1.ulaw' (language 'en')
[2013-09-12 14:04:45] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] file.c: -- <SIP/8881-00000006> Playing 'cannot-complete-as-dialed.ulaw' (language 'en')
[2013-09-12 14:04:47] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: == Spawn extension (from-internal, 12065551234, 6) exited non-zero on 'SIP/8881-00000006'
[2013-09-12 14:04:47] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: -- Executing [h@from-internal:1] Hangup("SIP/8881-00000006", "") in new stack
[2013-09-12 14:04:47] VERBOSE[10880][C-00000006] pbx.c: == Spawn extension (from-internal, h, 1) exited non-zero on 'SIP/8881-00000006'
```

Comment: Your SIP provider didn't recognize the number you passed to it. Check to make sure you formatted it correctly. If you need help you should contact them.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelHampton.  So how do I know whether I formatted the number properly?  I'm at lost here.

Comment: As I already said, you need to contact the provider to learn the correct format that they expect.

Comment: This provider in particular will accept almost anything, for north american numbers.  Interestingly, however, I don't see the presence of a Dial() function anywhere in there, but the dialplan that would have produced this is too complex for me to derive it just from this log.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm sure I must did something when I was trying to configure a new DID from Voip.ms. Suddenly my sip phone can't dial out. Tried to call extension to extension and having the same problem also.

Yup, sounds like you trashed your configuration while setting up the voip.ms stuff.

Undo your changes (get your system back to a working state), then contact the folks at `voip.ms` for assistance properly configuring your system to work with their service.